# How to underline text using Core Text?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-text

I can't find a simple example anywhere.  Here's where my code is at currently...

(Note: name is a UILabel, fontWithCTFont comes from a category of UIFont)

```
CTFontRef helveticaBold = CTFontCreateWithName(CFSTR("Helvetica-Bold"), 24.0, NULL);
[name setFont:[UIFont fontWithCTFont:helveticaBold]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[attrStr addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:style] range:range];` where style is a bitwise-mask combination of `CTUnderlineStyle` and `CTUnderlineStyleModifiers` values.

See my `OHAttributedLabel` class on github, and especially my `NSAttributedString+Attributes` category

Comment: Is it not possible to have my own gesture recognizer on an instance of this class?

Comment: Should be possible, the same way you can have it on a UILabel… Maybe try by setting the `onlyCatchTouchesOnLinks` to `NO`? (if set to `YES`, which is the default, the `hitTest:withEvent:` method -- that I override -- makes events pass thru the label, this is probably the reason the GestureRecognizer fails to work in such cases.

Comment: Note that the `onlyCatchTouchesOnLinks` property is useful to avoid stuff like UITableViewCells not catching the touch event in their `didSelectCell` delegate methods (as the `OHAttributedLabel` would catch the event before the cell does)… but in your case where you need to put a UIGestureRecognizer on your label, that's probably not the behavior you want anyway, so setting `onlyCatchTouchesOnLinks = NO` (to make the label catch all the event gestures and touches) is probably what you want instead of this default behavior of letting touches passing thru!